# How do I create a regex for only 2 capital letters?

Tags: regex

I don't have a lot experience with regex but I've trying all sorts of combination all day

Here is what I'm searching through

```
Continental EcoContact5 205/55 R16 0H MO
Goodyear EFFICIENTGRIP 205/55 R16 91H
Klebér DYNAXER HP3 205/55 R16 91H
```

and here is my regex `/([A-Z]{2})/` I only want the `MO` on the first line but I'm getting extra garbage with my regex

Comment: you should try http://txt2re.com/

Comment: @Leo: nice service, never knew about it. Could replace a whole lot of SO regex answers ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the language, you can use word boundaries `\b` around your pattern. A word boundary does not consume any characters, it asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not.

```
\b([A-Z]{2})\b
```

Alternatively, if not supported you could sort of create your own boundaries.

```
(?:^| )([A-Z]{2})(?: |$)
```